# Short way to return a long event listener

Tags: javascript

Sorry if I mess up anything, I'm new to coding.

I have an event listener that checks for actions within a video player in javascript.
There are a lot of events and instead of writing a new function for every one of them, I want to find a shorter way. The feedback from the listener should be displayed in the console (console.log)

It's a custom event listener but the code goes something like this:

```
const event = ["play", "pause", "mute"]
$player("myDiv").on(event, function() {
    console.log(??)
})
```

So basically is there a way to log which event triggered the listener in a short way without writing a separate function for each event?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know which event is fired at which action, you can register event listeners for each array.

```
const player = document.querySelector('video');
const eventTypes = ["play", "pause", "mute"];

// iterate over event types
eventTypes.forEach((eventType) => {

    // add event listener to current event type
    player.addEventListener(eventType, () => {
        // log current event type if event is fired
        console.log(`event of type ${eventType} was fired`);
    });
});
```

But if you want to specify a separate function for each event, you can write the following code:

```
const player = document.querySelector('video');
const events = [
    {
        type: 'play',
        callback() {
            console.log('play event fired');
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'pause',
        callback() {
            console.log('pause event fired');
        },
    },
];

// iterate over event types
events.forEach(({type, callback}) => {
    // add event listener for each event type
    player.addEventListener(type, callback);
});
```